# Burninate tags: search-algorithms and search-problem

Tags: discussion, tags

Why not just have a tag for searching? Searching is a problem, no need to add the word to the tag; and there's already a tag for algorithms. Come on, let's get rid of these.

EDIT:

As pointed out by Kaveh, search-problem has a more narrow technical meaning. While I am still personally unconvinced that this warrants having a tag for it, it can reasonably be taken as an argument in favor of having it. As such, you may feel free to focus on the search-algorithms tag, despite the apparent fact that search-algorithm can refer to exactly those problems which qualify as search-problems according to Kaveh's inferred usage.

Comment: I have never liked [tag:search-algorithms] (nor [tag:searching]). They are too vague to say anything; you can express any function in terms of searching (for the solution). Apparently, AI people use the phrase, though.

Comment: @Raphael I would call [tag:searching] (or, if pressed, [tag:search-algorithms]) the subject of chapter 6 of TAOCP.

Comment: "Burninate" ? what does that mean ?

Comment: @Gilles: Oh, well. That is authority right there.

Comment: @Suresh [The true meaning of burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/the-true-meaning-of-burninate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I favor using the simpler tag [searching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searching). Tags should convey information in a very short space, having a spurious word is bad. Questions about search algorithms are the dominant kind of search-related questions, so [search-algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-algorithm) doesn't convey useful information beyond [searching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searching).

Since [search-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-problem) [has a specific, useful meaning](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/burninate-tags-search-algorithms-and-search-problem/291#291), I'm for keeping it.

Comment: In the light of developments since, using [tag:searching] plus [tag:algorithms] seems advisable. But we *still* have (and use) [tag:search-algorithms]. Should we act in some way? ([Trigger](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/about-the-tag-graph-algorithms))

Comment: There's [tag:search] now, too.

Comment: @Raphael Any reason not to merge with [tag:searching]?

Comment: None that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

[Search problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem) is not what you think, it is a class of computational problems like decision-problems.

Comment: How is that not what I think? We have an "optimization" tag but not an "optimization-problem" tag; and besides, the definition you link to is just a generalized version of what people typically understand by searching, i.e., finding something in some data structure. I don't see the difference you're arguing for.

Comment: @Patrick87, this is a standard keyword in theoretical computer science, so having it as a tag is reasonable. Note that there is no algorithm involved here. About search-algorithms, I think what people normally mean is an algorithm for searching in a data-structure, not the class of computational problems I mentioned (although the wikipedia article for search-algorithms uses the generalization without any reference). I am fine with renaming/merging search-algorithms into searching or search. That plus algorithms tag should be enough. But I am in favor of keeping search-problem tag as it is.

Comment: I'll edit my post to focus on search-algorithms and admit that search-problem might be OK; we'll see how the community feels about them. Frankly, I'm unconvinced about the value of having a searching-problem tag, but you're free to disagree.

Comment: Please write a tag wiki for [tag:search-problem], if we end up keeping it. Having tag wikis that explain the tag to non-experts help demonstrate a tag's usefulness.